# shared pointer как прикрутить

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте есть задание, прикрутить к моему коду простейший SharedPointer. Программа у меня работает с операциями по модулю. Я читал что такое SharedPonter но понятия не имею как его сюда прикрутить 
Для примера кусок кода:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class IntMod
{
private:

    int num;
    int mod;

public:

    IntMod(int num = 0, int mod = 1) : num(num % mod), mod(mod) {}
    IntMod operator+(const IntMod& other);
    void get();
};

void IntMod::get()
{
    cout << this->num << endl;
}

IntMod IntMod::operator+(const IntMod& other)
{
    if (this->mod == other.mod)
        return IntMod((this->num + other.num) % this->mod, this->mod);
}

int main()
{
    IntMod a, b(13,21), c(10,21),d(5,21);
    a = (b + c);
    a.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Сюда как-то не возникает сильного желания добавлять SharedPtr, потому что у Вас каждый объект класса IntMod в общем-то ни с кем не разделяет права. Давайте так (для наглядности):  `int main()  {  shared_ptr<IntMode> a(new IntMode(42, 24));  { // зададим область  shared_ptr<IntMode> a2 = a;  }//В обычном случае здесь вызвался бы деструктор и при обращении к a получили бы ошибку  a.get();  return 0;  }`

Comment: @АлексейСаровский и как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Какую проблему?)

Comment: @АлексейСаровский собственно я не понял что вы написали за код, при попытки с компилировать у меня отвалились операторы, и полезло ряд ошибок.

Comment: В коде есть возврат объекта по значению, объект теоретически может быть любого размера, т.ч. разумно возвращать умный указатель, а еще круче на примере этого разобраться, как работает `std::move`.

Comment: Потому что можно заметить, что объект `IntMod` порождается, затем копируется, а сам умирает, затем копируется в `a`, а сам умирает.
Т.е. в процессе будет создано 3 экземпляра, два из которых будут уничтожены. С умным указателем или с move этого можно избежать.